# Populate Dropdown List based on Autocomplete Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have three form fields for country(text input), city(text input) and street(dropdown):

- country is autocomplete
- city is auto-filled based on the result of country
- street ***I want to generate dropdown list based on selected city***

Here is my current JavaScript script:

```
$(".country").autocomplete("get_city.php",{ mustMatch:true })   
  .result(function (evt, data, formatted) {
    $(".city").val(data[1]);
});
```

So far it's auto-filling the city(text input).

My problem now is to generate drop down list based on the filled city.

Comment: Do you have the street names in an array? If not, how do you plan on getting them?

Comment: i have a street database, im thinking of adding another query but i dont know where to start.

Comment: Query that database right after you set the city with the value of that city (`data[1]`

Comment: can you show me how to do it please? im a complete noob with javascript.

Comment: If it's possible, this can be with with php, since it's made to generate HTML. Then for each item we can loop through echoing each element in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you need somthing like this:

```
$(".country").change(function () {

    var webMethod = "filewithdata.php";
    var parameters = { id: $('.country').val() };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: webMethod,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

            //console.log(response);

            json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);

            var output = '';

            for (var i in json_obj) {
                if (json_obj[i][4] == 1) {

                    output += '<option value="' + json_obj[i][0] + '">' + json_obj[i][0] + '</option>'
                }

            }

            $('#dropdownElement').empty().append(output);

        },
        error: function (e) {
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");
            alert("Errror:" + e);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: should i echo the query results using json?  kindly provide some details with the php side.  thank you

Comment: Yes just uncomment the line  //console.log(response); you receive the answer in response varible. And check its contents on the console of your browser (F12, console)